# WCF UDP discovery only works for BasicHttpBinding not for NetTcpBinding

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding

I have a WCF service that has announced two service endpoints. One is for net.tcp and one is for http.

> net.tcp://localhost:11110/MyService
>
> http://localhost:11111/MyService

```
        // Make service discoverable 
        var discoveryBehavior = new ServiceDiscoveryBehavior();
        var announceEndpointAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AnnouncementEndpoint"];

        var netTcpBinding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None)
        {
            ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue,
            SendTimeout =  TimeSpan.MaxValue,
            OpenTimeout =TimeSpan.MaxValue,
            CloseTimeout =  TimeSpan.MaxValue
        };

        discoveryBehavior.AnnouncementEndpoints.Add(
            new AnnouncementEndpoint(netTcpBinding,
            new EndpointAddress(announceEndpointAddress)
        ));
        _serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(discoveryBehavior);
        _serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(new UdpDiscoveryEndpoint());
```

On the client side, I am using WCF Discovery.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var optionalBindings = new Binding[]
        {
            new NetTcpBinding(),
            new BasicHttpBinding(),
            new NetNamedPipeBinding()
        };

        var executed = false;

        foreach (var binding in optionalBindings)
        {
            var contract = ContractDescription.GetContract(typeof(IMyService));
            var endpoint = new DynamicEndpoint(contract, binding);

            var factory = new ChannelFactory<IMyService>(endpoint);
            var proxy = factory.CreateChannel();

            try
            {
                var result = proxy.GetData(123456);

                ((ICommunicationObject) proxy).Close();

                executed = true;
                break;
            }
            catch (EndpointNotFoundException)
            {
                // Ignored
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What confuses me is that it only works with BasicHttpBinding and never works with NetTcpBinding. So if BasicHttpBinding from optionalBindings list, i am not able to call the service although net.tcp endpoint is there.

Can anyone explain the reason for it?